# A Map<String, List<String>> implementation, exposing a view Map of "last values"

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons-collection

I'm looking at various [google-collections](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) (or also Apache [commons collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)) classes, and I'd fancy some help in finding the most appropriate Map implementation for my use case. I'm not interested in home-grown maps.

Here are some requirements:

- I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` data structure (A)
- Most of the time, I want to expose a `Map<String, String>` read-only view (B).
- (B) features:

  - Keys in (B) correspond to keys in (A)
  - Values in (B) correspond to the "last values in (A)", i.e. `B.get(X) == A.get(X).get(A.get(X).size() - 1)`
  - Values in (A) may not be empty lists

I know [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), but it doesn't expose a view satisfying my requirements for (B).

Any pointers?

Comment: Create your own implementation of Map. There is no such api which does this.

Comment: @VKSingla: Don't jump to conclusions, there might be a solution to my requirements. Guava is powerful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you just want [`Maps.transformValues`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Function-) from Guava:

```
Map<String, String> lastValueView = Maps.transformValues(originalMap,
    new Function<List<String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(List<String> input) {
            return input.get(input.size() - 1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Extending on @JonSkeet's answer, I would suggest that you use Guava's [`ListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) as your (A)  type. This type makes sure that you always have lists with at least one element as part of the map, and the [`.asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap%28%29) method returns a view that is a `Map<String, List<String>>` (even if the signature does not say so).

The [`Maps.transformValues`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method also returns a view, so changes in the source map are reflected in the target map. Be aware, however, that "The returned map is not thread-safe or serializable, even if the underlying map is.":

```
ListMultimap<String, String> source = ArrayListMultimap.create();
Map<String, String> target = Maps.transformValues(source.asMap(), new Function<Collection<String>, String>() {

  @Override
  public String apply(Collection<String> input) {
    return Iterables.getLast(input);
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, if I know that I have lists in my `Map`, I prefer to access the last item directly, instead of iterating...

Comment: @lukas-eder Iterables.getLast is smart enough about its parameters to use iterable.get(iterable.size() - 1) for all iterable instanceof List (and iterable.last() for all iterable instanceof SortedSet)